# Right way to pass a NULL Pointer to a out of process COM Method in an ATL Project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com, atl

What is the right way to pass a NULL Pointer to a out of process COM Method in an ATL Project? I have created a COM Server hosted through a COM Surrogate

If it matters I am using VS2012 running on Win 7. The Server Project is compiled in 64 bit and the Client Project in 32 bit

The IDL looks similar to below

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";
[   
    object, 
    uuid(37EFA952-7036-4398-93A6-6CDAD9DFC005), 
    dual,   
    nonextensible,  
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IGame : IDispatch
{   
    [id(1)] HRESULT passNull([in, out, unique] BSTR* avast, [out, retval] LONG* r);
};
```

The declaration is

```
STDMETHOD(passNull)(BSTR* avast, LONG* r);
```

and the definition

```
STDMETHODIMP CGame::passNull(BSTR* avast, LONG* r)
{   
    *r= 0;
    return S_OK;
}
```

And my client Code is

```
void main()
{   
    CoInitialize( NULL ) ;  
    IGamePtr p( __uuidof( Game ) ) ;    
    p->passNull(NULL);  
    p= NULL ;   
    CoUninitialize() ;
}
```

My understanding was, adding unique to the qualifier would allow me to pass a NULL through a pointer, but strangely, I keep on getting the message

```
_hr 0x800706f4 : A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.
```

Comment: Why at all you want to pass `NULL` pointers? I realize you want to leverage `unique` but it looks more a hack, isn't it safer to just not pass `NULL`s instead?

Comment: Why is this argument not [in,out]?  When it is just [in] then it should be BSTR, not BSTR*.

Comment: @HansPassant: Good to see you (I know you can save me :-)) . In any case it doesn't matter, even for [in, out] its the same. Question edited to change the argument [in, out]. Btw, as unique only applies to [in] I thought to keep it out of discussion

Comment: @RomanR.: This is a very simple example but in actual scenario, the behavior of the called function would vary based on the parameter value i.e. NULL or not NULL. If I have to ensure that I always pass a Not NULL, I need to maintain multiple versions of the same function. Consider the case, I am creating a wrapper over an existing functionality which can accept NULL and behave accordingly.

Comment: If this was all in process, it would work fine. Maybe a proxy/stub ossue. Could you elaborate on the "COM surrogate" you're using?

Comment: @SimonMourier:  Yes, its just what Windows provides, no custom Surrogate was used. In case you want to know about [DLL Surrogates](http://www.thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch12b.htm)

Comment: To find this on Google, a similar German error message reads "**An den Stub wurde ein Nullzeiger übergeben. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800706F4)**". We had this in the context of Active Scripting (VBScript) on a system where Active Scripting was corrupted, most likely due to a virus or an anti-virus tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are under false assumption that marking a parameter as [unique] is sufficient to let `NULL` pointers go through. This is not what is taking place actually.

By declaring your interface as `dual`/`oleautomation` as below, you register a universal proxy (also known as `PSOAInterface`) to marshal your interface between apartments.

```
[
    object,
    uuid(955C1132-96DC-4221-86A3-BE4C8CEB698C),
    dual,
    oleautomation,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IFoo : IDispatch
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT Bar1([in, unique] BSTR* psValue);
    [id(2)] HRESULT Bar2([in, out, unique] BSTR* psValue);
};
```

Universal proxy does not honor [unique] parameters and this is where you are getting stuck.

If you import the type library you created and/or check it with COM/OLE Viewer, you won't even notice unique specifiers there, and [PARAMFLAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not have a flag to help proxy understand the uniqueness.

This code would fail at specified lines:

```
A(pFoo->Bar1(&sValue));
A(pFoo->Bar1(NULL)); // <<-- A null reference pointer was passed to the stub. 
A(pFoo->Bar2(&sValue));
A(pFoo->Bar2(NULL)); // <<-- A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.
```

With your ATL project you typically have a satellite proxy/stub "PS" project. You don't need to use it for interfaces marshalled by universal proxy, however if you choose so, you will have your `[unique]` thing working.

This way, all four calls above will reach server without hitting `RPC_X_NULL_REF_POINTER`, with NULL arguments as you wanted. Your custom built PS takes you through the challenge.

Here is a test project if you want one: [NullBstrArgument](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/NullBstrArgument) (or, [SVN link](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/NullBstrArgument/)).

So you comment `dual`, `oleautomation` on IDL, you register both COM servrer and PS library, and on runtime you have:

```
psValue 0x007CE150 // #1 call argument on server side
sValue 0x007CE02C "Application"
psValue 0x00000000 // #2 call argument on server side, NULL is OK
psValue 0x007CE0D0 // #3 call argument on server side
sValue 0x007CE02C "Bar2"
psValue 0x00000000 // #4 call argument on server side, NULL is OK
```

#### Proxy/Stub Registration

Proxy/stub DLL project needs to be built first, however you need to take additional steps to activate its functionality:

1. The DLL needs to be COM registered with regsvr32
2. The DLL need to register its CLSIDs in registry as proxy/stub COM classes, this is not what is taking place automatically: you need to either build the PS project with `REGISTER_PROXY_DLL` (does not exist in default/template project) or otherwise the COM class in actual server need register itself appropriately putting PS registration into registry.

#### 32/64 Bitness

When server and client are of different bitness, including DLL surrogate hosting for server DLL, custom proxy/stub behavior is consistent: you can still pass `NULL` arguments and they go through fine.

The problem with bitness builds is that default Visual Studio project layout is setting up things confusingly and incorrectly, and solution is not trivial:

- you need to make sure MIDL compiler is executed with proper bitness/environment
- you need to make sure MIDL generated files are not confused between 32/64 builds, esp. making the files go to different directories, so that they are later included from respective locations

You also have to make sure that you have **both** Win32 and x64 PS libraries registered when your server is x64 only, but the client is Win32: the client still needs a 32-bit proxy.

Comment: I used your test project and it seems I cannot use the Satellite  Proxy/Stub instead of the universal Proxy/Stub in an Out of Process COM using surrogate process when the server and client runs in different bitness. When the 32 bit Client calls the QueryInterface, it peeks into the WOW6432Node to find the key ProxyStubClsid32 instead of searching in HKCR\Interface\{GUID}\ProxyStubClsid32

Comment: If you would like to take a look into what I am doing, you can check the attached files in https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790260/unable-to-pass-a-null-pointer-to-an-out-of-process-com-method-in-an-atl-project#details

Comment: x64 server as DLL surrogate works fine with win32 client, see my update above. I updated my project as well: if you build and register Win32 client, Win32 PS, x64 PS and x64 server - you will see it running with 2 processes and `NULL` are passed well, the same way as in simple in-process scenario.

Comment: Thank you Roman for your help. As a follow up to this question, can you provide me references which might be helpful in this regard? I have referred few Bookss on COM and ATL as well as extensively googled. But None was helpful.

Comment: You are welcome! Good books are all well known (such as Windows Internals and various MS Press series), but I can't think of any touching ATL and COM deeply and especially on the topic in question. Eventually it all goes to MSDN and documentation. Sorry for this, I'd be happy to refer to some precious source, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you are doing, the CGame::passNull() function gives no insight at all how the argument is supposed to be treated.  But the stub has a legitimate bitch, you really *are* passing a NULL pointer.  Valid client code would look like:

```
BSTR bs = NULL;
LONG r = p->passNull(&bs);
...
SysFreeString(bs);
```

Comment: I am speechless. Can you please explain, why is this working and not mine?

Comment: Compare to passing an argument by reference in the C# or C++ language.  The reference needs to be valid and non-NULL, since it yields the argument value storage location, the actual value may be NULL.  I don't know if MIDL has syntax to express that the reference may be NULL, just never used it myself.

Comment: I think I concluded too fast. The one you presented works because you are actually not passing NULL but a null terminated empty BSTR. They are two different things. As I have already assigned the Bounty, I will open a new one.

Comment: No, that's very much a NULL pointer.  There's no magic in a BSTR, it is just a typedef for a string pointer.  It doesn't spring to life until it is assigned from the return value of SysAllocString().  Beware of code that's happy to interpret a NULL as an empty string.

Comment: Well I am not too convinced. Reason 1: As I can see, you do not need a unique attribute to pass an empty null terminated string as we are doing here. Reason 2: If the parameter would have been like `long *`, this will not work. What I would love to is what is mentioned in the blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/05/26/142401.aspx. I understand this is pure COM, but a similar behavior I would want in my ATL code.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work in this case, but is your last comment implying that it bad design in general to interpret a null pointer as an empty string? If so, I'm curious as to your reasoning. That's something I do fairly often.

Comment: @CodyGray: I am not saying its a bad design, its something it will not work. I am creating a wrapper over an ODBC which accept null as arguments to pointer types, like `SQLLEN*` or `SQLWCHAR*`. Passing a null terminated string would require me to do more work which may not work in all cases, ex. `long *`.